# Returning 0 if MOD() divisor is 0?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use the `MOD()` function to set a cell to 1 or 0, depending on whether the *number* (`A2`) argument is divisible by the *divisor* (`B2`).

```
=IF(MOD(A2;B2)=0;1;0)
```

This works except when B2 is 0 (division by 0). How can I return 0 also in cases where the divisor is 0? Here's a failed attempt:

```
=IF(AND(B2>0;MOD(A2;B2)=0);1;0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=IF(B2=0;0;IF(MOD(A2;B2)=0;1;0))
```